# how to develop sql query generator via Fluent interface?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-interface, selectquerybuilder

i saw a article how to write a class which is a useful. the Class generates sql query via Fluent interface . But i am googling now but i can not find this excellent article. Do you know this article link :( or any other advise article or codes. Best Regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SelectQueryBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SelectQueryBuilder.aspx) is one example.

Or if you are sick of SQL you could also take a look at some ORMs such as NHibernate or EntityFramework which all have fluent interface syntaxes for querying data.